# Thymeleaf async processing

Tags: thymeleaf

I would use thymeleaf 3 template engine to include external/remote fragment.

Today I'm trying following syntax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Thymeleaf test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div th:insert="http://localhost:5001/"></div>
    <div th:insert="http://localhost:5002/"></div>
    <div th:insert="http://localhost:5003/"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

That works but if each services of each ports take 2 sec to respond the template will be generated at least after **2 + 2 + 2 = 6 sec**.

Whereas I was looking for something more async/parallel where template generation will be **MAX(2, 2, 2) = 2 sec** (+/- time to generate other things).

I don't find any built-in way to do but I'm not close to extend Thymeleaf 3, if you have any clue to where should I start and how.

---

PS: I know there is `DataDriven` feature but I'm not looking a async way to inject data, it's really an async way to process template!